# Lattice in order theory vs lattice as set of integer linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, order-theory

Are there any connections between these two definitions of a lattice?

- Let $B$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. A lattice $L(B)$ is the set of all integer linear combinations of the vectors in the basis.
- A lattice is a poset $(L, \leq)$ such that any two-element subset of $L$ has a unique supremum and infimum.

For example, can all sets that are lattices according to the second definition be seen as "discretizations" (might not be the appropriate term here) of vector spaces on some field? (That is, is there a sense in which they also satisfy the other definition?)

Comment: They have the same names (because when you draw them both resemble... lattices!) Not much more.

Comment: I'm not fluent enough in english, but why not use mesh instead of lattice posets? Or grid instead of lattices in $\Bbb{R^n}$? There is also netting. In French it is réseau and treillis.